# convert yaml array to string representation to export as environment variable with yq

Tags: bash, yq

I use yq to add environment vars from yaml files.

example.yaml:

```
var0: string0
var1: string1
ary0: ['aryval0', 'aryval1', 'aryval2']
```

code:

```
while read -r key val; do

    eval "export $key=${val}"
    
done < <(yq '.[] | key + " " + .' example.yaml)
```

error:

```
!!seq (ary0) cannot be added to a !!str ()
```

desired outcome:

The same yaml file gets read into bash, environment variables, ansible and php at different times for different purposes.

I need to catch array entries when reading the yaml file and convert those array entries into a string representation to export as an environment variable, but I don't know the syntax or methods to do this in yq.

array declaration and values; I don't know how to get the environment variable example to work:

```
ansible/yaml: ary0: ['aryval0', 'aryval1', 'aryval2'] 
bash: ary0=('aryval0', 'aryval1', 'aryval2') 
php: $ary0 = array('aryval0', 'aryval1', 'aryval2'); 
environment variable: ary0="aryval0:aryval1:aryval2"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the desired output for the YAML shown?

Comment: Ok, you say enviornment variables, bash doesn't allow to define arrays in environment. e.g. what should the value of `ary0` be? I get that `var0=string0`
and `var1=string1` are expected

Comment: Environment variables are a feature of the operating system, and POSIX allows only string values for the environment. You could simulate passing an array to a child process by creating a string representation of it, and turn it in your child process to an array.

Comment: @Inian Thanks for you input. I updated the question now that I understand the environment cannot use arrays. I don't know the syntax to catch arrays when reading yaml files and convert them to string representations.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for your input. I updated the question.

Comment: So, why not just `export DATA=$(cat example.yaml)`? `I need to catch array entrie` Do you really need _that_? What exactly do you _need_? As there _can't_ exist a service to require exported arrays, because it is not possible to export arrays, is this XY question?

Comment: It's not clear to me, why you need an **environment** variable for this purpose. If you need the same YAML information in bash and PHP, just process the YAML in each language to create a data structure for that language, and don't care about inheriting to children.

Comment: What is perhaps more important: How does the content of your array look like? In your example, each array element is a string consisting of letters and digits only. Is this always the case, or can them be arbitrary strings?

Comment: @user1934428 This is my first time posting a question here, and it sounds like I haven't made myself clear. multiple yaml files NEED to be read into the environment. Sometimes they contain arrays. yq throws an error when arrays are encountered (see question). I NEED a way to stop the error and load the yaml and I'd LIKE it convert the arrays in string representations in case I NEED them. Currently the arrays consist of only letters and numbers but I'd LIKE the option to include other characters that could be in an url and underscore. : / - _

Answer (score 2):

You can  do it in a `yq` script file like this:

bash.yq

```
.[] |(
    ( select(kind == "scalar") | key + "='" + . + "'"),
    ( select(kind == "seq") | key + "=(" + (map("'" + . + "'") | join(",")) + ")")
)
```

Then run it with yq like:

```bash
yq --from-file=bash.yq example.yaml
```

To get:

```bash
var0='string0'
var1='string1'
ary0=('aryval0','aryval1','aryval2')
```

Explanation:

- `.[]` matches all top level elements
- Then we're going to have a string expression for each of the different types that will product the bash syntax, and use the union operator `,` to join them together
- Scalars, we just need the key and quoted value: `( select(kind == "scalar") | key + "='" + . + "'")`
- Sequences (or arrays) are trickier, we need to quote each value and `join` them with `,`: `map("'" + . + "'") | join(",")`

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but with this `yq` (https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=example.yaml

eval "$(yq -r 'map_values(scalars)|to_entries[]|"export \(.key)=\(.value|@sh)"' $file)"
declare -p var0
for key in $(yq -r 'map_values(arrays)|keys[]' $file); do
    mapfile -d "" $key < <(yq --raw-output0 --arg key "$key" '.[$key][]' $file)
    declare -p $key
done
```